# Improve feature of watson conversation

Tags: watson-conversation

I had a query on the UI of the 'Improve' feature of Watson Conversation.Please refer below snapshot from my workspace:
[snapshot from the improve feature of WCS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEMlB.png)

How is that result count ( 7418 ) calculated?  Suppose in a single conversation , I had five questions and corresponding five responses from watson, is it a total of 10 results OR would it be 1 result..The reason I am asking is that the UI is confusing and I can see some repetitions , as I keep expanding the 'View conversation'.

Answer (score 0):

The result shows the user input along with how Watson Conversation classified the input (referred to as "questions" in your question above). Each variation is counted.

I believe there was a recent change the the UI that simplifies the search and lets you easily filter by entity or intent type.